# Decomposition of $\mathbb{M}^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Consider the subspace $W:=\Bigl \{ \begin{bmatrix}
       a & b  \\
      b & a \end{bmatrix} : a,b \in \mathbb{R}\Bigr \}$ of $\mathbb{M}^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I have a few questions about how this can be decomposed.

1) Is there a subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{M}^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $W\oplus V=\mathbb{M}^2(\mathbb{R})$? If so, what is one?

2) Further, is there a different (i.e., $\ne V$) subspace with the same property? And if not, is there a different proper subspace $U$ such that $W+U= \mathbb{M}^2(\mathbb{R})$?

**Which examples, if any, would work for these questions? I haven't made much progress, so seeing explicit examples and explanations would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$W = \operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\right\}.$$
Can you find a basis for $\mathbb{M}^2(\mathbb{R})$ that contains the above two matrices? Then the span of the new basis elements is your desired $V$.

Note that your question is exactly the same if you view the matrices as vectors, i.e., $W=\{(a,b,b,a): a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

---

Suppose $W = \operatorname{span}\{(1,0,0,1), (0,1,1,0)\}$.
The two vectors are a basis for $W$.
Can you extend $\{(1,0,0,1), (0,1,1,0)\}$ into a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$?
One way is $\{(1,0,0,1), (0,1,1,0), (0,0,0,1), (0,0,1,0)\}$.

I claim $V:= \operatorname{span}\{(0,0,0,1),(0,0,1,0)\}$ satisfies your condition 1). Indeed this follows from the definition of a basis.

This is not unique; there are other ways to extend into a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$. One other way yields $V:= \operatorname{span}\{(1,0,0,-1), (0,1,-1,0)\}$.

Comment: I still can't see it unfortunately. Also, wouldn't the span of the basis elements generate all of $\mathbb{M}^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Would you mind answering my original questions fully? I appreciate the response, but I haven't had any luck coming up anything.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you meant by the span of just the "new"  vectors. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, just a computational issue: For the second $V$ you give, how does $W+ V =\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 You are asking why the four vectors (basis of $W$ combined with basis of the second $V$) span $\mathbb{R}^4$. One way to see this is to show that the $4 \times 4$ matrix with these four vectors as columns is invertible.